# from PIL import Image api_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: docker, python-imaging-library

[image]After running with docker container **No module called docker is not found** error.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or error messages - prefer instead actual text - per Stack Overflow guidelines. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install pillow before running your container.

add `Pillow==9.0.0` in your `requirements.txt` file or add `RUN pip install Pillow` in Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you soo much, Its working.
but instead of running "RUN pip install Pillow" I just put 
"RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt"

Comment: great! it should work both way.

Comment: yeah, Thanks again.

Comment: if this answer solves your issue mark this one as accepted answer. thanks